# Como faço para visualizar os detalhes de uma Session do ASP.net no IIS como no Java usando o Tomcat?

Tags: asp.net, iis

No manager do Tomcat, temos como listar as sessões abertas e ver os "detalhes" de cada uma, inclusive ver uma lista de todas as variáveis de sessão (key-value) daquela sessão, como mostra a imagem exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe algo similar no IIS? tem como eu ver todas as variaveis de sessão de uma sessão ativa no IIS manager? se sim, onde?

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode habilitar o rastreamento no seu projeto, para isto basta adicionar a linha abaixo no seu arquivo Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" pageOutput="true" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

E depois de executar o seu projeto, basta adicionar o caminho: **/Trace.axd**
ao final da url.

Pode haver soluções mais elegantes, mas esta funciona bem.

Comment: Olá @CassioAlves , com essa informação, já ajuda, mas ainda não é exatamente o que eu precisava, optei por guardar as sessões no SQL Server e recuperar as variáveis de sessão com uma aplicação externa que desenvolvi para este fim. Mesmo assim, bem bacana esse trace.